# Unable to load mongo extension

Tags: php, php-mongodb

Suddenly I started getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Mongo' not found in /var/www/html/index.php

What could be the reason? `phpinfo()` and `php -m` is not showing mongo extension.

`extension=mongo.so` is present in correct loaded .ini file.

I even restarted the Apache server, but the problem remains.

```
phpinfo():
Loaded Configuration File   /etc/php.ini 

/etc/php.ini
extension=mongo.so
```

It was working earlier and I was able to connect to mongod server by `new Mongo()`.

Comment: Did you update PHP or something like that? What is your OS?

Comment: linux, i just removed ; from ;Default Value: E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE

Comment: Why did you uncomment this line?

Comment: oops that was the mistake, i should have used error_reporting:E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE instead of removing comment ; Please answer with this detail :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you have removed the comment on the wrong line, so it made your php.ini unreadable and so Mongo wasn’t loaded.

If you want to enable error_reporting you should edit that line:

```
error_reporting: E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
```

Answer (score 2):

It did not work for me. 
PHP Version 5.4.6-1ubuntu1

error_reporting : E_ALL | E_STRICT

If i comment this line, the mongo extension will be loaded.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have updated the PHP version. Try to install the mongo extension again.

For ubuntu execute this command:

```
sudo pecl install mongo
```